# To which SE site this question belongs?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask

> "which platform is better for earning money, WP, Android or iOS?".

But I am not sure to which of the site I should post it IF there is such a site.
And suggest a re-wording/editing if possible.
P.S. I am not even sure that the current question can be posted on SE Meta so if it does not belong here, do what you have to (downvotes, deletion etc) but please tell me the reason in comments. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This question is mostly opinion-based and is thus off-topic for the entire Stack Exchange network, since it'll generate lots of answers stating different opinions rather than proven facts.

---

Sidenote : if you are a good developer and you make good apps you'll earn money everywhere, no matter the platform.

Comment: It could be taken quite objectively if you include some stats and trends etc in the answer. No?

Comment: @kashanDanish that's what I thought at first, but info based on stats will be outdated every few months and would require constant updates so it's not a good fit for the SE network either.

Comment: So is the question "which platform is currently better for earning money, WP, Android or iOS?" viable?

Comment: @kashanDanish answerable on another site, probably. But it's not a good fit for the SE network, for the reasons mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I am not following, Problem: Opinion based | Solution: Include facts and figures, Problem: Stats get outdated | Solution: Rephrase the question as I mentioned, What are the reasons you are talking about?

Comment: @KashanDanish there won't be enough facts though, and the question will attract lots of low-quality opinion-based answers that we do not want. Same rules apply for your second question, plus the fact that the "currently" will be outdated soon and the objective of the SE network is to build a mass of quality questions/answers that will be useful for future readers, not just you.

Comment: @KashanDanish Stats are not always useful and can easily be tailored to meet the goals of the person posting the answer depending on which stats are used and where they came from. Just because an answer provides stats doesn't necessarily make it less opinionated.

Comment: [this](http://www.visionmobile.com/blog/2013/12/developers-prioritise-platforms-ios-vs-android-vs-html5/) seems pretty objective. I wanted an answer like this but not from a writer but from a programmer (or other related person). And yes stats are not "always" helpful.

Comment: A larger problem is that you haven't defined "better". Better in what way? What if you can earn 1½ times more money on one platform but the effort to create the app is 3 times as much? Would it still be worth it to you? There's too much opinion here. What you're really asking is "where should I focus my efforts next?" and no one can really answer that for you. Now, a question like "where can I find statistics on developer earnings for the various mobile app marketplaces?" _might_ be a reasonable question for a Stack Exchange site (but I don't think so).